# Help with a mod-rewrite rule

Tags: apache-2.2, mod-rewrite

How do I say, "if the file is in the `/wp-content/*` directory, serve it as long as it's `.+\.(jpe?g|gif|png|js|css)$`, otherwise throw a [F]orbidden."

I can't seem to wrap my head around where to begin.

I'm okay with regex, but my mod-rewrite skills are (obviously) lacking.

Comment: Both answers by serverninja and Born To Ride are correct, but note that the code should be `%{REQUEST_URI}`, not `{%REQUEST_URI}`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteOptions Inherit

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/wp-content/.*
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !.+\.(jpe?g|gif|png|css|js)$
RewriteRule ^/(.*)$ - [F]
```

I'm not at a machine where I can test it, but the idea here is two conditions that check for the wp-content directory in the URI, and then a negated condition for the files you want to serve statically. Everything else should put out a 403 error. If it's not right, it will certainly point you in the right direction ;-)

edit: syntax should be %{} not {%} -- thanks Jeff!

Answer (score 3):

A more compact version of *serverninja*'s snippet would be the following:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteEngine On
  RewriteCond {%REQUEST_URI} !^/wp-content/.*\.(jpe?g|gif|png|css|js)
  RewriteRule ^.*$ - [F]
</IfModule>
```